# if span has no text then hide span element

Tags: jquery, html

When a span has nothing inside of it I would like to hide the span using jquery.

My issue is that the spans contain a `<br />` and this causing my spans to still display.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <h5><strong>Billing Address</strong></h5>
    <p class="address-fields">
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.Name @Model.BillingAddress.Surname<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.CompanyName<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.AddressLine1<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.AddressLine2<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.AddressLine3<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.City<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.StateTitle<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.PostCode<br /></span>
        <span>@Model.BillingAddress.CountryName</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.address-fields span:empty').hide();
```

Comment: `$('.address-fields span').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().trim() == ''}).hide();`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Works a treat! Thanks